# Send UART break

Tags: microcontroller, uart, gpio

I need to talk to a chip that requires UART break on it's RXD pin (my TXD) for 1 second.

I use ZW0301 controller and it's UART controller **does not** support break commands. Is it possible to *emulate* break command? May be it is enough to disable UART controller (to put pins into GPIO mode) and put TXD low. Or this will not work?

A link to a good description is appreciated.

Comment: Yes, although I've never tried it in practice, setting `P1.0` to GPIO mode/low for 1 second should work just fine.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson do I need to disable h/w UART controller on these pins before operating using GPIO commands?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, as Joachim said, pulling TXD low for more than character time will work. And yes, those pins will need to be in GPIO mode for that to work.

Another option for generating break is to set a lower baudrate, and send 0 character. (so TXD will be low for >1 character), but for your case, this is not really an option.

You'll almost surely have to go the GPIO way for 1s break condition.